# Run multiple commands sequentially

Tags: batch-file

I'll try to keep this short...I'm new to using batch files, so bear with me.  But here's what I'd like to happen:

- Open cmd.exe
- Change to a directory
- Execute a file in that directory

Here's what I've done so far:

```
cmd.exe /k "cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
```

Now I'd like to execute a file that's in the desktop directory.  I was reading that you could something chain commands together with `&` or `&&` (`cmd.exe /k "cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop" && "test.exe --config=test.txt"`) but I haven't had any luck.

How would I go about adding another command such as `test.exe --config=test.txt` to be run after I changed to the desktop directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing quotes at the end of the first command and the beginning of the second command.  Something like: `cmd.exe /k "cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop && test.exe --config=test.txt"`

This just worked for me. `cmd /k "cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop && FileCrc.exe"`

Comment: Thanks.  That worked well.  If I wanted to separate these on to separate lines for readability, is there a trick to doing that?

Comment: The line continuation character is "^".  However, I'm not sure if it will work inside of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mess around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add the following to a file and name it runtest.cmd.

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d "%userprofile%/desktop"
test.exe --config=test.txt
```